# What mood is "non avere paura!"?

Tags: verbs, moods

I just found a sentence that is:

> Non avere paura! Il suo cane è buono.

However, what is the mood of the verb `avere`? The meaning is pretty clear but it sounds like an imperative form. In that case, it should be:

> Non abbi paura! Il suo cane è buono.

So what mood is it?

Comment: It's the imperative. See [this other question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/6043/707).

Comment: In Italian, the negative form of the imperative is constructed with the infinitive.

Comment: @Charo Thanks. Is the rule always true?

Comment: Yes, it's always that way.

Comment: See, for instance, http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2010/06/03/ripassiamo-limperativo/.

Comment: You can also find it here: http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/grammatica-italiana/imperativo-italiano.htm.

Comment: @Charo Thanks but it is too difficult for me since it is written in Italian...

Comment: I see... The relevant information is that you should use the infinitive when constructing the negative form of an imperative.

Comment: Would you add the tag "tenses" and remove the tag "conjunctions" to to your question?

Comment: Just to be a nit-picker: imperative is a mood, non a tense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb is at the imperative because when you face an imperative in the negative form (example in English: *Do not feed the animals*), the imperative becomes infinite:

Non fumare/Vietato fumare (*Do not smoke*).

Non dare da mangiare agli animali (*Do not feed the animals*).

Non avere paura (*Do not be afraid*).

Comment: Why a "strong" negation?

Comment: I would simply say something like "the negative form of an imperative".

Comment: It's used also with simple negations but imperative is often used with exclamations, prohibitions, strong suggestions,... Moreover, as in English, if you read "Don't worry" or "Do not worry" you can feel the difference of expressivity in the two sentences

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who are you talking with. If you are talking to a friend you can use "Non aver(e) paura!"

"Non abbia paura!" is much more formal.